# Creating a polygon in ActionScript 3 from a set of coordinate pairs

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm making an app in Flash, and I want to define some polygons which I can bind hover events to to add annotations to an image.
I can create these normally in Flash, but I want to load some external data, a list of coordinates, and create the polygons with ActionScript.

Obviously they're just hotspots, so I want them to be invisible, but searching for my problem only shows results for drawing polygons from coordinates using the `graphics` property of a `movieclip`.

The data doesn't ever change, so it would be possible to just draw all the polygons manually with the pen tool, but the data is being used elsewhere, so it would be much easier to maintain if I could add new zones just by updating the text file.

Comment: Can you clarify your issue here? Are you saying that you want to be able to draw the polygons in the IDE and save their vertices, so you can re-draw them later? You said they don't ever change... so if you're going to draw the polys in the first place, why don't you just save them as movieClips in your library and add them to your pictures.... the saving of the vertices and re-building from scratch at runtime becomes redundant.

Comment: No, I only ever want to draw them programatically. I was saying that, in theory, I could draw them in the IDE, but because they are based on data that I'm using elsewhere, I'd rather draw them with actionscript because then I can update one data source and have all the things that use it update simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var pointsRawXML:String = '<mypoints>\n<point x="100", y="100 />\n<point x="100", y="0 />\n<point x="0", y="0 />\n<point x="0", y="100 />\n</mypoints>';
```

Will give you:

```
<mypoints>
    <point x="100", y="100 />
    <point x="100", y="0 />
    <point x="0", y="0 />
    <point x="0", y="100 />
</mypoints>
```

Then you load and parse it:

```
var points:XML = new XML(pointsRawXML);

var pointsXMLNodeList:XMLList = points.children();

var i:uint = 0;

var pointsVector<Point> polygonPoints = new Vector<Point>();

for(i = 0; i < pointsXMLNodeList.lenght(); ++i) {
    var tmpXML:XML = XML(pointsXMLNodeList[i]);
    var pX:Number = tmpXML.attribute("x") as Number;
    var pY:Number = tmpXML.attribute("y") as Number;
    var p:Point = Point(pX, pY);
    polygonPoints.push(p);
}
```

Now you can draw out the polygon inside the graphics object of a sprite:

```
//Note we can recycle the "i" variable
var polyContainerSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
polyContainerSprite.graphics.beginFill(0, 1);

for(i = 0; i < pointsVector.length; ++i) {
    if(i == 0) {
        polyContainerSprite.graphics.moveTo(pointsVector[i].x, pointsVector[i].y);
    }else {
        polyContainerSprite.graphics.lineTo(pointsVector[i].x, pointsVector[i].y);
    }    
}

stage.addChild(polyContainerSprite);
```

Something like that should work. Note all that code is untested and it's been about a year since I've actually made anything in flash. lol so test and if you have any questions/concerns let me know I'll help clarify.

Also note that you're going to need to basically adjust this code to "loop" 'n' times, for each poly/sprite that you need. Also note you can save your XML into files and just load them up sing the URLLoader object, and casting the data to an XML.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with the `graphics` property? Assuming you have an array of point coordinates (`x0, y0, x1, y1, .. xN, yN`) for a polygon then you can add a polygon hotspot like this:

```
var hotspot:Sprite = new Sprite();
var g:Graphics = hotspot.graphics;
// fill with an alpha of 0, so the shape is invisible
g.beginFill(0xffffff, 0);
for(var i:int = 0; i < polyCoords.length; i += 2){
    if(i == 0){
        g.moveTo(polyCoords[i], polyCoords[i + 1]);
    } else {
        g.lineTo(polyCoords[i], polyCoords[i + 1]);
    }
}
g.endFill();
// add a mouse-event to the hotspot etc.
hotspot.addMouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK, hotspotClickHandler);
addChild(hotspot);
```

Your coordinates can be a simple stream of numbers, which you convert to an array using [String.split](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#split%28%29)

Comment: Ah ok, that works great. I assumed that drawing graphics like this would create a bounding rectangle around the polygon, that would fire events even for the bits outside the polygon. That's the only reason I was looking for a more abstract polygon representation, but this was the solution all along. Thanks.

Comment: @espekia, it will create a bounding rectangle and it has. Pixel perfect collision detection (even collision with the mouse) must be done with a bitmap object.

Comment: @AscensionSystems I don't understand what you mean. Using a sprite with dynamically drawn graphics as described above will create a vector shape and only trigger mouse-events when the mouse hits the shape (**not** the bounding rectangle)

Comment: @bummzack ummm unless they recently changed this in the flash VM, I believe you're mistaken. Can you point me to some reference material?

Comment: @AscensionSystems it has been that way since [Graphics](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html) was introduced and that's already a while back...

Comment: btw. you're doing exactly the same in your answer... just overcomplicated

Comment: @bummzack thanks for correcting me on the vector graphics thing. I was totally mistaken. I'll +1 you for that. As far as my answer being over complicated, it's actually a complete implementation rather than a demonstration of the concept. The person who posed the question can now essentially copy and paste that right into his code it will do exactly what he needs, as per his requirements. There's a difference between over complicating something, and inherent complexity in a real-world solution.

Answer (score 0):

The XML:

```
        <mask>
            <point x="30" y="10" />
            <point x="50" y="10" />
            <point x="50" y="30" />
            <point x="30" y="30"/>
        </mask>
```

Actionscript

```
    public function paint(points:XMLList,maskColor:uint = 0xFF0000):void{

        var mask:Shape = new Shape();
        mask.graphics.beginFill(maskColor);     

        var i:int = 0;
        for each(var xnNode: XML in points) {       
            if (i==0){
                mask.graphics.moveTo(xnNode.@x, xnNode.@y);
            }
            mask.graphics.lineTo(xnNode.@x, xnNode.@y);
            i++;
        }
        mask.graphics.endFill();    
        this.addChild(mask);            
    }
```